# How to fix Unknown dereferenced type ARRAY when posting an article using LinkedIn API

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am setting up the ability to post to LinkedIn depending on what the user wants to post. The options are currently just text or text with a link. Posting just text works without issue, but when I try to add a link I receive an unclear error from LinkedIn.

The code that I am using to pass the request along to cURL is:

```
$Header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$Header[] = 'x-li-format: json';
$Header[] = 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0';
$Header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>';
$Header[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($FieldsArray));
$Curl = curl_init('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts');
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $Header);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($FieldsArray));
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$Response = curl_exec($Curl);
curl_close($Curl);
```

With $FieldsArray being the following array.

```
array(4) {
  ["specificContent"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["media"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["status"]=>
        string(5) "READY"
        ["originalUrl"]=>
        string(24) "<URL>"
      }
      ["shareCommentary"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(4) "test"
      }
      ["shareMediaCategory"]=>
      string(7) "ARTICLE"
    }
  }
  ["author"]=>
  string(28) "urn:li:organization:<ORGANIZATION ID>"
  ["lifecycleState"]=>
  string(9) "PUBLISHED"
  ["visibility"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility"]=>
    string(11) "PUBLIC"
  }
}
```

Using a similar array without the URL and shareMediaCategory:None returns the following:

`object(stdClass)#15 (1) { ["id"]=> string(32) "urn:li:share:<SHARE ID>" }`

I would expect something similar with the above array, but instead, the response is:

`Unknown dereferenced type ARRAY for DataMap's schema { "type" : "array", "items" : { "type" : "record", "name" : "ShareMedia", "namespace" : "com.linkedin.ugc", "doc" : "Media that has been shared.", "fields" : [ { "name" : "title", "type" : { "type" : "record", "name" : "AttributedText", "namespace" : "com.linkedin.common", "doc" : "A text with attributes within it", "fields" : [...`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received this error due to incorrect formatting of media in the JSON request object. However, I believe in your case you are incorrectly specifying the media asset. Refer to the following API docs for uploading images and obtaining the digitalMediaAsset ID to be used for posting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#create-an-image-share

In PHP before json_encoding for the request, the following format works for me.

```php
$postStatus['specificContent']['com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent']['shareMediaCategory'] = 'IMAGE';
$postStatus['specificContent']['com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent']['media'][] = $media;
```

where **$media** itself is an array:

```php
Array
(
    [status] => READY
    [media] => urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:abc123
)
```

**Note:** The digital media asset may not be fully uploaded before you make the request. You can use the Assets API to check the status of the image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api

Comment: This was the solution that I found as well. In my case, due to the fact that I am including a published external article, using `$FieldsArray['specificContent']['com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent']['media'][] = array("status" => "READY",  "originalUrl" => $LinkToPost) ` worked.